# Sharepoint 2010 List adaptor for SSIS 2016

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-2010, ssis-2016

### Background

Migraing from SSIS 2012 to 2016. Connecting to an exisint Sharepoint 2010 site.  Using SSDT for VS15. In SSIS 2012 project, we used SharepointlistAdapters from CodePlex.

### Problem:

When loading 'old' project, I get the error that the Sharepoint.conmgr failed to run.

### Question

Is there a new Sharepoint List adapter for SQLServer 2016 or we could use the same ones as 2012?

### Update

Ijust installed SharepointlistAdapter on my pc and then reopened. As with previsous versions,we could add the Sharepoint Adapter list components under Tools > Choose Tool Box items. But in SSDT15, once in Tool box items, I cannot see the tab "SSIS Data flow items" and "SSIS Control Flow Items".
Is SSDTV15 not compatible with SharepointListAdapters?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest release from GitHub. I'm running it fine with the latest version of SSDT.

You can find the latest release on https://github.com/fan130/mssql-ssis-community-samples/releases